# Caesar Cipher improvement

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

Currently, I have this and it's working for all cases:

```
import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

def caesarCipher(s, k):
    st = []
    for i in range(0,len(s)):
        if 65<=ord(s[i])<=90: 
            temp = ord(s[i])+k%26
            if (temp>90):
                temp-=26
            st.append(chr(temp))
        elif 97<=ord(s[i])<=122:
            temp = ord(s[i])+k%26
            if (temp>122):
                temp-=26
            st.append(chr(temp))   
        else: st.append(s[i])
    return ''.join(st)




if __name__ == '__main__':

    s = input()

    k = int(input())

    result = caesarCipher(s, k)
```

I'm not sure if the multiple `if` loops reduce readability. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Sample I/O:

```
Input: s = middle-Outz , k=2
Output: s = okffng-Qwvb

Input: s = Always-Look-on-the-Bright-Side-of-Life ; k=5
Output: s = Fqbfdx-Qttp-ts-ymj-Gwnlmy-Xnij-tk-Qnkj
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Review

- Remove unused imports

  You don't use *any* of these imports, just remove them to reduce clutter
- Read [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) the python style guide

  1. Functions and variables should be `snake_case`
  2. There should be a `<space>` in between operators
- Instead of appending to a `list`, you could create the `string` for the start

  So instead of making `st = []`, do `st = ''` and `st += char`, no need to join then

  However you could make the shifting a separate function, and then `''.join()` becomes needed again
- When looping, loop over the item not the index

  Instead of `for i in range(len(s))` you could directly loop over the char --> `for i in s`
- There is a function to determine if we encounter an uppercase or lowercase

  You could use [`char.isupper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isupper) or [`char.islower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower)
- Simplify the shifting

  You could use the fact that if you subtract the start `ord('a')` or `ord('A')` and then modulo, the extra check of `if temp > x` becomes not needed
- Notice how the operations for each case (upper, lower) are mostly similar

## Putting it all together

```
import string
APLHA_LEN = len(string.ascii_lowercase)

def shift_letter(letter, shift):
    start = ''
    if letter.isupper():
        start = ord('A')
    elif letter.islower():
        start = ord('a')
    return chr((ord(letter) - start + k) % APLHA_LEN + start) if start else letter

def ceasar_cipher(st, shift):
    return ''.join(shift_letter(letter, shift) for letter in st)
```

**BUT, there is a better way...**

As mentioned by someone already you could use the [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) function very nicely for ceasar ciphers.

Giving you something like this

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as lc, ascii_uppercase as uc

def ceasar_cipher_translate(st, k):
    trans = str.maketrans(lc + uc, lc[k:] + lc[:k] + uc[k:] + uc[:k])
    return str.translate(st, trans)
```

*NOTE That this code assumes Python3.x*

Comment: A magic number `26` is still lingering. Consider something along the lines of `len(string.ascii_lowercase)`.

Comment: @vnp Done, that slipped my mind :)